# Postgres login via localhost timeout

Tags: postgresql, rails-postgresql

I've installed Postgres.app and modified the port number to 5466, I've enabled listen_addresses='*'.

I've setup 'trust' in pg_hba.conf.

I can connect through the socket via psql. However, psql -h localhost -p 5466 fails and returns *"server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request."

Port 5466 is mapped to postgresql.

Any help as to why I can connect to the socket, but not to localhost would be appreciated. If i connect on another port an error is returned instantly telling me there is no server there, but when I connect on the correct port the connection hangs and returns the error above.

Comment: What do you mean by "Port 5466 is mapped to postgresql"? ssh tunnel perhaps? Is the `psql -h localhost` being run on the same physical machine as postgresql is running on?

Comment: Set `log_connections = yes` in postgresql.conf and look into what the server reports about these aborted connections or connection attempts in the server log.

Comment: In /etc/services, port 5466 is assigned to the postgres process. log_connections is set to yes. 'psql -h localhost -p 5466' is being run on the same physical machine as postgres.

Comment: log_connections printed out this before psql returned the error from the     original post.

    `LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-01-29      07:34:16 GMT-10

    LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress

    LOG:  record with zero length at 0/16C9C18

LOG:  redo is not required

LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=51037`

Comment: It later printed `LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=51031
LOG:  incomplete startup packet`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a program to monitor internet traffic blocked all ports other than 80: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/169